# What should be our standard for creating speculative craft/mission tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

So today I came across [falcon-super-heavy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falcon-super-heavy). There's [one question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26281/what-would-be-reasonable-payload-capacities-of-falcon-super-heavy-to-various-ref), and it links to [an article](https://www.theverge.com/2018/2/5/16975850/spacex-falcon-heavy-launch-elon-musk-tesla-questions) that talks about it in theoretical terms

> Musk was asked whether SpaceX can increase the Falcon Heavy’s performance over time, much like it has with the Falcon 9. That’s when the CEO suggested the possibility of a Falcon Super Heavy — a Falcon Heavy with extra boosters. “We could really dial it up to as much performance as anyone could ever want. If we wanted to we could actually add two more side boosters and make it Falcon Super Heavy,” Musk said. This five-rocket Falcon Super Heavy would have around 9 million pounds of thrust, Musk said, nearly doubling the rocket’s current capability, and putting it in line with the Saturn V as the most powerful rocket ever built.

Elon Musk is a starry-eyed optimist and he talks a good game, but typically backs it up with actual development. But FSH is more along the lines of this concept

> We strapped 2 rockets onto another one, why not 5?

What's different about this, vs [bfr](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bfr), is that BFR has some actual development behind it (they've at least built a tank). Maybe FSH will become a thing, but there's only Musk's one quote about it and it's far from the only project being talked up without any actual development (see [mars-one](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mars-one), which [appears to be a Mars-mission PR firm](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12166/does-mars-one-actually-do-anything)).

How much speculation do we tolerate in creating new tags?

Comment: I went ahead and removed the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Summary: Speculative concepts should require a large number of net positive scored questions prior to meriting a tag.

Sometimes we have a problem that it's not clear where the line is. In this case, I would say it is rather clear that this has crossed the line. As you said, it is one question about something that Musk mentioned one time. That doesn't need a tag. Now, if we had a lot of questions about it, maybe we could justify needing a tag, even if it was just a concept. There's no need to preemptively create a tag for it though, especially since the name of this concept could change if Musk does pursue it.

Comment: a lot gets read into (and written about) things Musk tweeted once.